# Detect blob in very noisy image

Tags: python, image, computer-vision

I am working with a stack of noisy images, trying to isolate a blob in an image section. Below you can see the starting image, loaded and plotted with python, and the same image after some editing with Gimp.

What I want to do is to isolate and recognise the blob inside the light blue circle, editing the image and then using something like `ndimage.label`. Do you have any suggestion on how to edit the image? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This question is to broad really. There's lots of ways to do it, one would be to measure the brightness of pixel areas averaging the total of 10x10 pixels and if all pixels happen to be close to the blobs average then you have a blob, finding out the size of the blob is a bit more tricky but you could go about it the same way, find 10x10 pixels matching a certain average brightness and then traversing outwards in all directions until you hit a "wall" and then you follow that "wall" until all pixels matching up the average brightness has been found.

Answer (score 2):

The background looks quite even so you should be able to isolate the main object using thresholding, allowing you to use array masking to identify regions within the main object. I would have a go with some tools from scikit image to see where that gets you http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/

I would try gaussian/median filtering followed by thresholding/filling gaps. Or you could try random walker segmentation, or pherhaps texture classification might be more useful. When you have a list of smaller objects within the main object you can then filter these with respect to shape, size, roundness etc
http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_label.html#example-plot-label-py